# import json in python script not working in intellij

Tags: python, json, intellij-idea

I use json library for load json files. In Visual Studio Code it works perfect, but in Intellij IDEA, I have problem.

[image]

When I try to use, I get error: AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'.
[image]

[image]

This is just in intellij problem. In databricks work fine.

[image]

Comment: Please try to post the real code instead of screenshots. Also, I cannot figure out the sense of the second and third screenshot. Where is the error?

Comment: What is the name of your file you are using?

Comment: @ahuemmer error is null for `print(json__file__)`, I think that this is a path for json library.

Comment: @quamrana It is not json.py, is configuration.py

Comment: Is there another file called `json.py` in the same folder? That's the only way I could get this to fail.

Comment: I still don't get it... Is the error `AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'` or is it `json.__file__` being null? Where does `loads`(especially with the trailing s) come from?

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot you use: "json.load"
In the last screenshot you use: "json.loads"